# Как подключить файл EJS после условия?

Tags: node.js, ejs

Как подключить файл EJS после условия? Вот типо этого

`<% if(true) %>
 <%-  include('../views/replays.ejs'); -%>
 <% }; %>`

Без условия все прекрасно подключается, а с - нет

Comment: а зачем минусы тут? `<%-`, `-%>`

Comment: это ничего не меняет, на оф странице написано, что лучше так

Comment: просто [вот тут](https://github.com/makersacademy/slack-overflow/issues/89#issuecomment-396767669) почти как у тебя пример и вроде как работает